# How to find the miss rate in a cache friendly code?

Tags: c, caching, multidimensional-array

```
int sumarrayrows(int a[M][N])
{
    int i, j, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            sum += a[i][j];
    return sum;
}
```

I was wondering how to find the miss rate of any cache friendly code and does measure the size of a cache or a cache block if so how to find the size of it.

Update I figured out how to find the miss rate

Since this uses 4 bytes 
there will be a 25% chance of a miss rate
    a[0] = M
    a[1] = H
    a[2] = H
    a[3] = H

Comment: Valgrind's cachegrind shows cache statistics. You could also use some CPU-level profiler (VTune, perf, oprofile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your platform. Most modern CPUs have hardware performance counters which could potentially be used to count cache-misses, but access to these may be awkward. Windows, for example, generally expects you to write a kernel-mode driver.

You might be better off getting some decent performance analysis software and running your code through that.